# Partially Transparent Text When Sticky Div Site on Top of a YouTube iFrame

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, youtube, opacity, sticky

I have a nav element that sticks to the top of the page and when it rests on top of the embedded YouTube iframe it makes the text in that sticky nav element more transparent (maybe by ~30%). This only happens in Chrome (my version is 23.0.1271.97).

You can see that the issue doesn't appear in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BFTrick/kvZCj/4/) but it will appear on a local HTML file or a file on the web.

[image: screenshot]

Here's the code:

```
<style>
a{
    color: white;
}
#primaryNav
{
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
}​
</style>

<div style="height: 400px;"></div>

<div id="primaryNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Open House</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shadow Days</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Curriculum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<iframe width="350" height="197" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XfX2lvFbWlc?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<div style="height: 600px;"></div>​
```

This happens with both YouTube and Vimeo but doesn't happen with some other sites like my companies site or my personal site so I would assume somehow the hovering div is somehow interacting with the content of the embedded webpage which is confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try seeing if it's something to do with the wmode attribute. Try setting

```
?wmode=transparent
```

for the iframe.

If that doesn't work, it might be something to do with the z index of both elements.

Comment: I did it like so but no effect. `http://www.youtube.com/embed/XfX2lvFbWlc?rel=0&wmode=transparent`

Were you at least able to replicate the issue so that I know I'm not going crazy?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I'm actually not getting that issue anymore, running Chrome 23.0.1271.97.